# Does this special function exist?

Tags: functions, special-functions

Is it possible to find a non-trivial function $f(x_1,x_2)$ that has two parameters $x_1$ and $x_2$.

This function should satisfy
$f(x_1,x_2) = f(\frac{x_1}{1+r},x_2 +r)$, for any non-negative $r$.

For instance, if $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1 x_2$, then $f(x_1,x_2) = f(x_1 r, \frac{x_2}{r})$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to form a group, where addition of $r1$ then $r2$ is the same as adding $r1+r2$.  But then 
$$f(x1,x2)=f(\frac{x1}{1+r1+r2},x2+r1+r2), or\\
f(x1,x2)=f\left(\frac{x1}{1+r1},x2+r1\right)=f\left(\frac{x1}{(1+r1)(1+r2)},x2+r1+r2\right)$$
so $f$ has to be independent of $x1$.

Comment: You could have $f(x1,x2)=f(e^{-r}x1,x2+r)$

Comment: Great idea. If $f$ has to be independent of $x_1$, then it has to be independent of $x_2$. Therefore, $f(x_1,x_2)$ is a constant and it only has the trivial solution.

Comment: To make sure it's independent of $x_1$ it would seem one needs to be able to fix $k=x_2+r_1+r_2$ arbitrarily, and then show all $x_1$ give the same value of $f(x_1,k).$ This method here allows only certain changes in the first coordinate, given a specific choice of $k=x_2+r_1+r_2.$ (I might be missing the point here...)